# Flutter // FIrebase : Wait for a ListView widget to load to display it

Tags: flutter, firebase

**Click to see my issue :** [Image of my probleme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THhoQ.gif)

Hello, please,
As you can see above, the widget is displayed when it is built. I would like to be able to load a widget while the widget is being built and display it completely.

```
StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return SizedBox(); // Indicateur de chargement en cours
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Erreur: ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          final comments = snapshot.data ?? [];

          if (comments.isEmpty) {
            return Text("Aucun commentaire.");
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  itemCount: comments.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 5),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final commentData =
                        comments[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    final uidCommentaire = comments[index].id;
                    final uidUserCom = commentData['uidUserCom'];
                    print(uidUserCom);

                    // Utilisez la fonction Commentaires pour créer chaque élément de la liste
                    return Commentaires(
                      uidCom: uidCommentaire,
                      uidUserCom: uidUserCom,
                      uidAnnonce: uidAnnonce,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                if (visibleCommentCount < totalCommentsCount)
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: loadMoreComments,
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      overlayColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Charger plus de commentaires",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: kColorPrimary, // Couleur du texte en orange
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return SizedBox();
          }
        },
      ),
```

1. Change

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return SizedBox(); // Indicateur de chargement en cours
          }
```

by

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Indicateur de chargement en cours
          }
```

Doesn't work.

2. Add isLoading variable :

```
bool isLoading = true;
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Simulate a delay of 2 seconds before showing the ListView
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: [isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : MyWidget()])...
```

Doesn't work, same result as on the screen.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to show loading widget on dropdown change? Also you can just compare  `if(snapshot.hasData)..else`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did but doesn't work :-(

Comment: It would be great if you can share full sample widget with dummy stream(counter..) that reproduce the same error.